# Computing a Maximal Independent set using Depth First Search

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

> An independent set of an undirected graph G = (V,E) is a subset I of V such that
>   no two vertices in I are adjacent. That is, if u and v are in I, then (u,v) is not in E.
>   A maximal independent set M is an independent set such that, if we were to add
>   any additional vertex to M, then it would not be independent any more. Every
>   graph has a maximal independent set. (Can you see this? This question is not
>   part of the exercise, but it is worth thinking about.) Give an efficient algorithm
>   that computes a maximal independent set for a graph G. What is this method’s
>   running time?

I am not exactly sure if a modification to depth first search produces a solution to the above given problem but here is my attempt (note: I am not looking for code, just a high level description of what I should do)

Using DFS, we are going to traverse all the vertices of the graph starting from some start vertex S1. From S1, we go to an adjacent edge S2, if no adjacent edge exists we add S1 to the maximal independent set M since this vertex has no edges between any other vertex in G, if this is the case then we choose another vertex S1' and do DFS from that point (recursively).

Suppose that there is an edge between S1 and S2, then we can add S1 to the independent set but not S2, then the DFS continues, we add S3 because S3 shares no edge with S1, the DFS continues and what we do is we keep adding S[k] to the set M as long as it shares no edge with the current elements already existing in M.

This will take us O(|V| + |E|) time complexity. Reason: DFS is O(|V| +|E|), each time we move to a new node we have to check it against some K elements in M to make sure they don't share an edge. That is O(k (|V| + |E|)) = O(|V| + |E|).

Worst case: The empty graph, |V| calls to DFS giving us O(|V| (|V| + |E|)

Questions:

**(1) Is this correct, did I actually find the maximal independent set or the maximum independent set ?**

(2) If correct, is this efficient ?

If totally wrong, I would really appreciate a solution, I have thought about this problem for some time now.

Comment: You give a "time complexity" of O(|V| + |E|), and then a "worst case time complexity" of O(|V|(|V| + |E|)).  Which is it?  Or what is the first one measuring?

Comment: To my understanding, an approach that is easier to understand would be a [connected component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling), which is basically a depth-first searchm and afterward select a single node from each connected component; the time complexity would also be `O(|V| + |E|)`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I guess I should have just provided one time complexity, the first one I provided is on average for any graph G, the worst case is the empty graph. I provided both as I did not know which one it was asking for. The question did not specify what type of graph G is. So I had to make assumptions.

Comment: We're usually interested in the worst-case complexity.  Also, it's not clear that your first time complexity actually is an accurate way to describe the average complexity -- nothing I can see stops k from being proportional to |V|, and if that can happen, then the average-case complexity is also O(|V|(|V|+|E|)).

Comment: There is currently no known efficient algorithm solving your problem.

Comment: @piotrekg2 The problem above is NP-Complete, I believe that you can find the maximal independent set of any graph but not the Maximum.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm - ah sorry, I did a mistake, I was talking about "maximum of maximal independent sets".

Comment: @piotrekg2: Finding a maxim***al*** independent set is easy to do in polynomial time.  Finding the overall maxim***um*** is NP-hard.

Comment: @libik Why did you remove your answer ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm - it was wrong (even the second one)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve it:

Input: A set of vertices `V`, adjacency lists `E[v]` (one for each vertex):

1. Prepare an array `take[]` of size `|V|` containing `bool` values. All elements are set to `false` initially. This array tells us which vertices are taken into result.
2. Set `take[0]` to `true`.
3. For each vertex `v = 1..|V| - 1`: if `E[v]` contains no edge `(v, u)` such that `take[u]` is `true` then set `take[v]` to true.
4. Return all vertices `v` such that `take[v]` is `true`.

The total time compexity is `O(|V| + |E|)`.